# Angular API reference code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I'm learning Angular js from their API references I've watched a few tutorials and I learned some basics of Angular js bindings however this code is not running properly 
I checked it 1.1 1.2 and 1.3 but not working.

```
ngapp References
```

Here is the link API reference [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)

And here is JsFiddle[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ecrppoL0/)

Where am I making mistake??
Where should I start to learn ? 
Or this references is outdated?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem was the order of initialization. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ecrppoL0/1/) loads Angular in the head, not on load.

[The docs on Angular bootstrapping](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) explain how Angular is initialized. This particular issue is related to how JSFiddle first loads external 'onload' resources, before running your JS code, after [the `onload` event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) has been fired: Once Angular is loaded (if loaded during `onload`), it will immediately evaluate your template and look for `ng-app` to bootstrap things and kick it all off. But at that point, JSFiddle has not run your JS code yet.

Also; rule #1 of web development: Always keep the console open.